# Install Windows 7 Manually

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, windows-installation, repair-install

My Windows 7 is in a black screen with cursor before login in all boot modes state. It says I have no restore points (when I actually do) and I have tried all recovery options. It happened after I ran CHKDSK /r on the drive in a cmd in WinRE. I have another working computer and a Win 7 retail disc. Can I extract the Win7 Ultimate directory from the install.wim and completely replace the C:\WINDOWS\ directory through a linux boot CD? Are there any files I want to keep intact to boot correctly (obviously the drivers folder but what else). Is there a way to do a repair install like I can do in XP? I'm running out of options.

Comment: windows 7 has 2 options. Custom and Upgrade. Have you tried both? One option might involve a parallel installation i.e. windows in another directory.

Comment: I heard you need to boot into Windows to upgrade.

Comment: maybe, but if that's so, it's only true of upgrade. What about Custom?  I think you're probably right re the upgrade option. so windows 7 has no repair installation like xp has that you can boot off cd for. But you can choose custom and install another copy of windows 7 on that computer. possibly on the same partition.

Comment: a custom install deletes all of your personal data and all of the programs

Comment: I have an XP dual-boot though and I can boot into that

Comment: you wrote "a custom install deletes all of your personal data and all of the programs"  If that is the case, and i'm not sure that it is, but if that is the case, then you could create it on a new partition. Boot gparted live off a cd. you can resize the old partition make it much smaller. Create a new partition, install windows 7 on that new partition.

Comment: I have over 300 GB of files in my partition, I DO NOT want to do that.

Comment: I see you don't have rep to join a chat. that's ok can talk in comment. And you don't want to copy the files off the partition onto an external hard drive. Ready to then copy onto a new partition created by gparted live?

Comment: I dont have enough space on my drive to have XP and dead 7 and data

Comment: you would if you copied your data to an external drive, then could even backup the external drive again if you want. Then remove the data from dead 7.  And by the way, best practice generally involves backing up even in the xp days when it was definitely possible to do a repair installation 'cos techies often don't trust windows installations to leave files, for some reason. I'd add, I have installed windows 7 when I already had it,n recall a windows.old  folder.And not clicking format is probably fine. But it's risky if unsure.But if you google you'll see such a thing as windows.old re win7.

Comment: If you want to be risky and not back up, then try installing windows 7 off cd, ignore the uprade option 'cos you're right it doesn't work booting off cd. But choose Custom.  I don't see why it should wipe your c:\users directory. And it might even pop up a message about moving windows to windows.old   If a message comes up that it'll wipe all data then you might want to leave it.

Comment: your previous windows installation on that partition probably won't be bootable, but I doubt it'd wipe any of your data(if you don't format!). that said, it's always safer to backup. And if you're backing up, then no harm in removing the data from the dead 7. and removing the entire dead 7 in fact.

Comment: well if my answer won't satisfy this question I can't imagine what kind of answer would xD

Answer (score 1):

Even if you manage to extract the `installer.wim` from the windows installation media, replacing your windows files will only further damage your current system.

I recommend you to create a Windows 7 System Repair Disk; you will need a working Windows 7 System for that:

- Open the Start Menu, then type `recdisc.exe` in the search box and press Enter.
- Insert a *blank* unformatted CD or DVD into your CD/DVD drive and click on the Create disc button. 
  NOTE: If you are prompted to insert a Windows installation disc, it means that the files needed to create the system repair disc cannot be found on your computer. Insert a Windows 7 installation disc.
- It will now start creating the System Repair Disc.
- When it's finished, click on the Close button.
- Click on OK
- Remove and label your new Windows 7 System Repair Disc from the CD/DVD drive.

[Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2083-system-repair-disc-create.html)

Then use the newly created repair disk to repair your damaged system.

Alternatively you can try [Hirens Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)([Download](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) / [Boot From Pendrive](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd-on-usb-disk)).

Hirens Boot CD Features a Mini Windows XP which can allow you to determine the root of the issue and - if possible - fix it.

In case all fails, install a new windows on top of your current windows (`Custom Install` `***`). All your files will be moved to `Windows.old` folder on the root of the drive and the drivers will be located in `Windows.old\Windows\System32\Drivers`.

However this approach does work, it is recommended to download setup packages for drivers from your pc manufacturers website.

Sidenote:
If you have registered programs, most programs store their license information in the Registry(`Windows.old\Windows\System32\config\`), AppData (`Windows.old\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData`) and ProgramData(`Windows.old\ProgramData\`)

You can [mount the old registry entries from your old system into a hive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuSxbDIlFW0) in the new system.

Just make sure you copy over all the programs stuff into the same locations on the new OS and copy the license information / registry entries (`Export -> Unmount Hive -> Import`).

Another Note:
if the folder `Windows.old` already exists, the folder all your current files will be moved in will be `Windows.old (2)` etc...

`***`Make sure to select the correct partition of your broken OS, AND **DO NOT** FORMAT, just continue installing.

Comment: I will  try this with a spare XP computer first and see if it works. Thank You. I have a complete XP dual-booted with the 7 install. How would I find the root of the problem using a full XP?